# How to toggle a button className based on a checkbox being selected (react)?

Tags: reactjs

I would like to change the Button from "btn-default" to "btn-warning" when any of the checkboxes are selected on the page...

I have already set up the state for toggleActions and set it to false as default...

How do I toggle the state to true when any select boxes are selected on the page...

Button:

```
<button
  className={`btn waves-effect waves-classic mr-2 ${
    component.state.toggleActions ? "btn-warning" : "btn-default"
  }`}
  type="button"
  id="dropdownMenuButton-contacts-actions"
  data-toggle="dropdown"
  aria-haspopup="true"
  aria-expanded="false"
>
  Actions
  <span className="icon md-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true" />
</button>
```

Checkbox:

```
<td class=" cell-30">
  <span class="checkbox-custom checkbox-primary checkbox-lg">
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      class="contacts-checkbox selectable-item"
      id="contactName501049"
    >
    <label for="contactName501049" />
  </span>
</td>
```

Comment: What is `component.state.toggleActions`? What value/values does it hold? When you toggle the checkbox values how are you getting those values to do the classname check?

Comment: @Drew Reese  component.state.toggleActions... holds a boolean value... toggleActions: false

Comment: If `toggleActions` is simply a boolean then your code looks to be correct for setting the classname. What about how you save the toggled state from the checkbox input? How are you getting that value? Please update your question with complete component code.